# Cross table query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

**course**
idcourse
name

**mark**
idmark
idstudent
idcourse
mark

**student**
idstudent
name
How to cross a query to such a result?

 **result**
table Header

```
studentid   course1 course2 ... courseN

id1         mark1   mark2   ... markN

id2         mark1   mark2   ... markN

id3         mark1   mark2   ... markN
```

Comment: Looks like a job for a temporary table or SPROC. An easy way would be to return `id1 mark1`,`id1 mark2`,`id1 mark3`...etc using a join. I don't see it being "good practice" to have a query with a variable number of columns though. And in the event that there are fewer results for `id1` than there are for `id2` what would be the anticipated result--NULL?

Comment: so the expected result NULL or 0

Comment: This is more of a display problem than a retrieval problem. It's trivial to make a 3-way join query. it'd be way easier to just have your app do the horizontal viewing than trying to get a query to do it for you

Comment: So you propose to put to work creating this query on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can think if is to use the `group_concat` function.
Because a variable number of columns is just a maintenance nightmare.
You can strip the values from the `coursegrades` field apart by `exploding` the list in php or whatever comma separator you have in your client.

```
  /*First make a list of coursenames for the header.*/
  SELECT 'studentid' as idstudent
    , 'studentname' as studentname
    ,  GROUP_CONCAT(course.name ORDER BY couselist.idcourse) as coursegrades
  FROM course
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT idcourse FROM mark) courselist
    ON (courselist.idcourse = course.idcourse)

UNION ALL 

  /*UNION ALL this with a list of grades per course*/
  SELECT idstudent
    , student.name as studentname
    , GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(mark.mark,'') ORDER BY courselist.idcourse) as coursegrades
  FROM course
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT idcourse FROM mark) courselist
    ON (courselist.idcourse = course.idcourse)
  LEFT JOIN mark ON (mark.idcourse = courselist.idcourse)
  INNER JOIN student ON (student.idstudent = mark.idstudent)
  GROUP BY student
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should have many-to-one [foreign](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) [key](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_Create_foreign_key_contraints.php) relationships to insure that the idstudent field in the tables depending on the student table idstudent field (mark, course) match up.

To answer your specific question, it's not possible to return a result like this from the database client. Maybe if you wrote something as a procedure, but not with basic SQL. The best way to get the results you want is to do a simple query on the mark table to get the idstudent and mark fields and then manipulate them externally in another language.

So the query would be like this:

```
SELECT marks.idstudent, marks.mark, courses.name FROM marks,courses
WHERE marks.idcourse=courses.idcourse;
```

And you can display the results using an external program written in PHP or Python, for example.

Comment: As Johan explained, its really not a good idea to return these kinds of results using SQL.